# How to limit the fields of the associated models using find method

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

I have user model and articles model. An User hasMany articles. So when I query for a user, all fields for article table is retrieved. I want to limit it just title of articles.

```
$user = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $id), 'fields' => array('User.firstName', 'Article.title')));
```

The fields works fine for user model. But it does not work for associated models. throws error

```
SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Article.title' in 'field list'
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're better of using [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable), and it's just as easy:

```
$this->User->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
$user = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $id), 'contain' => array('Article.title'), 'fields' => array('User.firstName')));
```